# How to detect placeholder text is overflowing in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My question is about is there any way using JavaScript or CSS to detect the placeholder of an input field is overflowed? 
We have a lot of methods to find entered value in the input field is overflowed or not. We can use `scroll width` and `offset width` for this. But the scroll width is not working for placeholder. 
we can give `text-overflow: ellipsis` of CSS to show the ellipsis on the overflowed placeholder. But I can't find any CSS or Javascript methods to detect whether the ellipsis is applied to a place holder or the placeholder text is overflowed in an input field.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: It means you want to overflowed the placeholder of input.

Comment: you can set id on input tag, then do what ever you want to the selected tag... do you want something like that?

Comment: Will the placeholder change during runtime? Can I know the use case why you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple:

```js
const isPlaceholderOverflowed = inputId => {
  const input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  input.value = input.placeholder;
  const isOverflowed = input.scrollWidth > input.clientWidth;
  input.value = "";
  return isOverflowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MasihJahangiri answer I managed to make a Directive in Angular-14:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[AutoResizeInput]',
})
export class AutoResizeInputDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() clientPlaceholder = '';

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const input = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

        if (!this.clientPlaceholder.length || this.clientPlaceholder == undefined || this.clientPlaceholder == null) {
            throw new Error('AutoResizeInputDirective - Input element must have "clientPlaceholder" property defined!');
        }

        input.setAttribute('value', this.clientPlaceholder);
        const css = `width: ${input.scrollWidth}px`;
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('style', css);
        input.value = '';
    }
}
```

And in templates Input element just added:

```
<input
    cbpAutoResizeInput
    [clientPlaceholder]="item.placeholder"
    ... />
```